# Calling newInstance() when creating a child fragment extending a parent fragment

Tags: java, android, class, oop, android-fragments

I have a parent DialogFragment called TheParent and a child Fragment called TheChild which extends TheParent.

However, I need to be able to initialize some variables in TheParent even though I am instantiating TheChild, so what I tried was:

In the parent

```
public static TheParent newInstance(int myInt) {
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    TheParent fragment = new TheParent();
    args.putInt(ARGUMENT_MYINT, myInt);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}
```

and then in the child:

```
public static TheChild newInstance(int myInt) {
    return super.newInstance(myInt);
}
```

However it does not like me doing this because of the static context.

What is the correct way to call newInstance() on TheChild and have it invoke newInstance() of the parent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Static methods, like new instance in TheParent are "class" methods. Therefore, instead of calling super.newInstance, you should be calling TheParent.newInstance (...). Just remember the way to call static methods is by using the class name. Hope it helps.
All that said, the newInstance method in TheChild has a return value of type "TheChild". This means that returning a "TheParent" instance would be impossible, it would result in a compile time error that you will see as soon as you change the code in TheChild from:
"return super.newInstance()" to "TheParent.newInstance ()".

Comment: So how do I declare/set up the child properly if the parent requires an argument in order to be set up? The parent needs myInt

Comment: Put the initialization code in the parent class in a private constructor that takes an int. Then call that constructor from TheParent.newInstance and pass it myInt. In TheChild class then, you will need a constructor that also takes an int and calls super(myInt) which is the parents constructor that you just created, and in the TheChild.newInstance you will call this constructor in TheChild and pass it myInt. This way, both the child and parent will run the parents initialization code and the fragment created in TheChild will be of type TheChild and not TheParent.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did to keep from having to repeat all the logic in the child class:

```
public static TheChild newInstance(int myInt) {
    TheChild fragment = new TheChild();
    fragment.setArguments(TheParent.newInstance(myInt).getArguments());
    return fragment;
}
```

Of course, this solution creates a second instance of `TheParent` momentarily.